# Doubt about とは in this sentence

Tags: grammar

From Naruto chapter 670,

[image]

I have doubts about とは in this sentence

> 言葉の探求一般、学問全般**とは**あいまいなものであり

I wonder if this と is used for comparison. 言葉の探求 is あいまいなもの compared to 学問全般?

Comment: @aguijonazo Ah so this defining とは d? But how should I understand 言葉探求一般?

Comment: It’s just saying “Pursuit of language in general, learning in general is …”

Comment: Note that とは is not strictly for the formal definition but also for critical/inherent characteristics of something.